# SVG rect border width

Tags: svg, rect

Is it possible to manipulate SVG rect's borders in the same way as it `border-left-width`, `border-right-width` and so on does?

Comment: What do you mean by the rect's borders? Do you mean the stroke properties? That definitely can't be done. I'm pretty sure you can't selective change the left or right parts of the rect (other than their position).

Comment: Yes, I mean the stroke properties of the borders. You can put it as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you asked, the answer, I'm afraid is no. If you want to selectively change the sides of a rectangle, you'll have to draw it as four separate lines.

Answer (score 16):

try this and change it as yours.

```
<svg width="400" height="110"> 
   <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you control which side has the border? e.g if someone only wanted a border on the top, left and right.